# Which is faster custom query using @Query vs findAll() thru CrudRepository?

Tags: java, sql, database, hibernate, jpa

I was writing Java code to get all the rows from the database table.

I was using CrudRepository and used this method below.

```
public interface StudentRepository extends CrudRepository<Student, Long> 
{
    public List<Student> findById(long id);
}
```

or

```
@Query(value = "SELECT s FROM Student s")
List<Student> customMethod(long id);
```

Which method is faster? Does Java internal method provide faster than our custom query?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I initially thought I misread your question, but then I realized you asked for getting all rows, while both snippets showed a method taking `id` as a parameter. Please make up your mind ;)

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Answer (score 1):

The default `findById` provided by Spring Data Repository and a query-annotated method have significantly different semantics. But, to keep it short, I will try to focus on differences in performance exclusively.

Unless you have query cache enabled, a query-annotated method **will always hit the database** with a query.

`findById`, on the other hand, ultimately calls `EntityManager.find()`. `EntityManager.find()` **looks up the entity in the persistence context first**. That means if the entity has already been loaded into the context, the call **will not hit the underlying database**.

As a side note, if you're curious as to how Spring implements the default repository methods, have a look at the source of `SimpleJpaRepository`.

Comment: by our answer can we say we should use query methods instead of @quey

Comment: If you mean that we should prefer `findById()`, then *effectively*, yes. You have to understand that JPA will **never** load two copies of the same entity into the same persistence context. If the entity already is in the context, even if you do `SELECT .... WHERE id = :id`, ultimately you'll be getting the already loaded version, but still a query needs to be executed. That's because queries are always run against the DB, never against the in-memory cache.

Comment: Note that this conclusion is **not** true for other repository methods like `findAll()`, because internally, they use queries (unlike `findById()`)

Comment: suppose I have to find the data based on two columns for e.g : @Query("SELECT t FROM Todo t where t.title = ?1 AND t.description = ?2")
    public Optional<Todo> findByTitleAndDescription(String title, String description);

Comment: and second option we have public Optional<Todo> findByTitleAndDescription(String title, String description);  Now if JPA already loaded this entity in Context then there is no need to use @Query annotation. But my question how we will know JPA has loaded this entity in his context.

Comment: This answer is *specifically* about `JpaRepository.findById(...)` vs a custom method with `@Query("SELECT e FROM Entity e WHERE id = :id")`. All other custom finder methods will need to execute queries, whether you use `@Query` or not

Comment: Note that the following statement: 'JPA will never load two copies of the same entity into the same persistence context' still holds for any custom query: if the query returns 5 entities, for instance, and 3 of them are already loaded, the result list will contain the 3 loaded instances + 2 instances freshly loaded into the context

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203896/discussion-between-sumit-kandoi-and-crizzis).

Comment: i need to understand if the entity is already in context and then if we use custom query methods then why it is firing a query to DB?

Answer (score -1):

You have to understand that `findAll()` method eventually generates the query for the selection. The only way to prove that is to test it. I don't think you will gain a significant performance boost. JPA's, on another hand, query generation is extremely easy to understand and use. So, if you hesitate between using one or the other, I would stick to `findAll()` JPA or spring data repository methods.